# Evaluate indefinite integral using susbtitution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I have the following integral to evaluate. I think it should be done by substitution but I get stuck midway when I use $u=x^5$ and $du=5x^4dx$

$$\int x^{14}\sqrt{x^5+2}\,dx$$

Comment: Edit your question to show the integral that you get after the $u$-substution and indicate where, exactly, you are stuck.

Comment: What about $u^2 = x^5+2 \implies 2u \, du = 5 x^4 \, dx$?

Comment: @KStarGamer Since I can't recommend a better alternative, your approach may be best.  However, the three issues that it will raise are : [1] What if $(x^5 + 2) < 0$.  Wouldn't the substitution break down here? [2] $~\displaystyle x^{(14)} = \left[(u^2 - 2)^{(14)}\right]^{(1/5)}~$ which results in an integral that can be routinely calculated, but is somewhat messy. [3] $~\displaystyle dx = \frac{2udu}{5(u^2 - 2)^{(4/5)}}~$ is also no walk in the park.

Comment: @user2661923 To answer [1], it would produce an imaginary part but that would be expected if $x^2+2<0$ any way, and any imaginary constants would be absorbed into the integration constant. To answer [2] and [3], $\int x^{14} \sqrt{x^5+2} \, dx = \int x^{10} \sqrt{x^5+2} \cdot x^4 \, dx = \int (u^2-2)^2 \cdot u \cdot \frac{2}{5} u \, du$. Expand and integrate termwise.

Comment: @KStarGamer Nice response.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sqrt{x^{5}+2}$, then $2 u d x=5 x^{4} d x$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int\left(u^{2}-2\right)^{2} u \cdot \frac{2}{5} u d u \\
&=\frac{2}{5} \int\left(u^{6}-4 u^{4}+4 u^{3}\right) d u \\
&=\frac{2}{5}\left(\frac{u^{7}}{7}-\frac{4 u^{5}}{5}+\frac{4 u^{3}}{3}\right)+C \\
&=\frac{2 u^{3}}{525}\left(15 u^{4}-84 u^{2}+140\right)+C \\
&=\frac{2\left(x^{5}+2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{525}\left[15\left(x^{5}+2\right)^{2}-84\left(x^{5}+2\right)+140\right]+C \\
&=\frac{2\left(x^{5}+2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{525}\left(15 x^{10}-24 x^{5}+32\right)+C .
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!